# Flutter - How to get Container with children to take up entire screen

Tags: dart, flutter, flutter-layout

As per Flutter docs `Containers with no children try to be as big as possible unless the incoming constraints are unbounded, in which case they try to be as small as possible. Containers with children size themselves to their children.` The closest I've been to getting it to work:

```
return Stack(
  children: <Widget>[
    Container(
      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
      height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
      //width: Device.screenWidth,
      //height: Device.screenHeight,
      child: Column(
        children: <Widget>[(view[1])],
      ),
    ),
    Container(
      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * .50,
      height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * .50,
      child: Column(
        children: <Widget>[(view[0])],
      ),
    ),
  ],
);


I/flutter (12292): The following message was thrown during layout:
I/flutter (12292): A RenderFlex overflowed by 81 pixels on the bottom.
I/flutter (12292): The overflowing RenderFlex has an orientation of Axis.vertical.
I/flutter (12292): The edge of the RenderFlex that is overflowing has been marked in the rendering with a yellow and
I/flutter (12292): black striped pattern. This is usually caused by the contents being too big for the RenderFlex.
```

Can't understand why MediaQuery or Device isn't preventing overflow? The first Container always overflows by 81 pixels on both an Android phone or tablet; no iPhone or iPad to test now. Based on what I've read from other posts overflow with yellow & black is corrected simply by wrapping in a SingleChildScrollView but when I attempt to do so I get

```
child: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[(view[1])],
        ),
      ),

I/flutter (12292): ══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY RENDERING LIBRARY ╞═════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
I/flutter (12292): The following assertion was thrown during performLayout():
I/flutter (12292): RenderFlex children have non-zero flex but incoming height constraints are unbounded.
I/flutter (12292): When a column is in a parent that does not provide a finite height constraint, for example if it is
I/flutter (12292): in a vertical scrollable, it will try to shrink-wrap its children along the vertical axis. Setting a
I/flutter (12292): flex on a child (e.g. using Expanded) indicates that the child is to expand to fill the remaining
I/flutter (12292): space in the vertical direction.
I/flutter (12292): These two directives are mutually exclusive. If a parent is to shrink-wrap its child, the child
.
.
.
I/flutter (12292):   crossAxisAlignment: center
I/flutter (12292):   verticalDirection: down
I/flutter (12292): This RenderObject had the following child:
I/flutter (12292):   RenderAndroidView#e356e NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT
```

Made several other attempts with Expanded, ClipRect & other widgets based on the errors I've seen but it just made it worse where there was no image at all. Am I missing something simple or should I attempt to fix this another way?

EDIT: As per Amsakanna the latest attempt is below but still overflows by 81 pixels to produce identical error message above in the first code block.

```
return Stack(
  children: <Widget>[
    SingleChildScrollView(
      child: Container(
        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
        height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[view[1])],
        ),
      ),
    ),

I/flutter ( 1144): The following message was thrown during layout:
I/flutter ( 1144): A RenderFlex overflowed by 81 pixels on the bottom.
I/flutter ( 1144): The overflowing RenderFlex has an orientation of Axis.vertical.
I/flutter ( 1144): The edge of the RenderFlex that is overflowing has been marked in the rendering with a yellow and
I/flutter ( 1144): black striped pattern. This is usually caused by the contents being too big for the RenderFlex.
```

Tried to use IntrinsicHeight inside SingleChildScrollView as found [here](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/SingleChildScrollView-class.html) in the **Expanding content to fit the viewport** section but it overflows too (by 81 pixels) with similar error message.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Maybe give some details. Because a simple `Stack` with a `Container` as a child should use the full screen, if you place two `Container` as a `Stack` children be aware that only the second will be visible, it's a stack after all, so it's on top of the first.

Comment: What is inside (view[0]) and (view[1]) ? They might be the source of the problems.

Comment: @MiguelRuivo I'm stacking 2 camera views on top of one another. Similar to the FrameLayout in Android. Currently both are visible, it's just the first that repeatedly overflows

Comment: @Willy both view[0] & view[1] are cameras. The second container sizes correctly as per MediaQuery.... * 0.50 but the first keeps overflowing. Seems I'd have issue with both views if they're the source of the problem...

Comment: What do you mean by camera views?

Comment: @MiguelRuivo see the link: https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/camera

Comment: In the second container, you're setting height = device width. Is that intentional or typo?

Comment: See above edit as tried @Amsakanna suggestion but still overflow by 81 pixels

Comment: Do you have an AppBar too?  I'm wondering if that is causing the overflow since your size math is referring to the full screen size rather than the available body size.

Answer (score 55):

SizedBox.expand did it for me.  Here is an example of displaying an image so that the image height matches the parent and the container draws a black background in the unused space:

```
  SizedBox.expand(
    child: Container(
      color: Colors.black,
      child: Image (
        fit: BoxFit.fitHeight,
        image: AssetImage('assets/myimage.png'),
      ),
    ),
  );
```

Answer (score 11):

My approach...

```
return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Title'),
      ),
      body: Container(
        color: Colors.indigo[200],
        alignment: Alignment.center,
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Container(
              child: Image.file(_image),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
```

Comment: Please add more detail to explain your solution.

Comment: @Nakx Check doc for "alignment": "If non-null, the container will expand to fill its parent and position its child within itself according to the given value." Specifying alignment basically makes container expand to fill parent.

Answer (score 2):

It works for me..

```
return Scaffold(
              appBar: AppBar(
                title: Text("chatEasy"),
                backgroundColor: Color.fromRGBO(102, 108, 218, 1),
              ),
              body: Container(
                child: Column(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Expanded(
                      child: Container(
                        child: Image(
                          image: AssetImage("images/baseScreen.png"),
                          fit: BoxFit.fitHeight,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            );
          }
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

Wrap the Container with a SingleChildScrollView() and give the container the height and width using MediaQuery. I could achieve the results using this way. This way, the screen doesn't overflow by any pixels.

```
return Scaffold(
  body: SingleChildScrollView(
    child: Container(
      height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
      child: , //child 
    ),
  ),
);
```

Answer (score 1):

wrap the `Container` with `SizedBox.expand` and add colors in SizedBox.

Answer (score 0):

You did it right by wrapping it inside a SingleChildScrollView.

The second error happens whenever you have a flex widget like 'Expanded' is placed inside a Column. If you did not place any expanded widget inside the first Column, probably it is the Camera widget doing that.

**Try giving a definite size to your Camera widget by wrapping it inside a Container or SizedBox**.

Comment: thanks for catching typo above, it should be height = ...size.height. Yes view is expanded as want to fill all available space...

Comment: In that case, you should wrap your column inside SingleChildScrollView with a container of device width and height.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to make a container height as much as its child take you may use this approach.

```
     Card(
           
            child: Flexible(
              child: Container(
                
                child: Column(
                  children: [
                    Container(
                      height: 30,
                      width: double.infinity,
                      color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
                        child: Align(
                              alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                              child: Container(
                                  margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 5),
                                  child: Text('Presupuesto Por Profesional',style: 
                  TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 16,fontWeight: 
                FontWeight.bold)),
                              )
                        )
                ),
                    ProfessionalTableView(reportData.presupuestos)
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            )
          ),
```

My `ProfessionalTableView` is a dataTable and its length depends upon the size of the list I pass it. So the card size also depends upon the item I have in list.I wrap the parent `Container` with `Flexible` and it work.

Answer (score 0):

wrap your content inside a **Positioned.fill**

```
Positioned.fill(
      child: Visibility(
        child: Container(
          color: Colors.black54,
          child: Center(child: PRLoader(),))
        ),
    )
```